# Can Imageio.getwriter to use codec 265?

Tags: ffmpeg, python-imageio

I have pip installed imageio[ffmpeg] (2.34.0), but the only FFMPEG codec the imageio wrapper seems to support is h264. When I run the below code with the following codecs, I get the error:

I am trying to get DEVS or DEVLS codecs from the FFMPEG -codecs for my non-audio mp4 videos, any suggestions?

```
from imageio import get_writer 
writer=get_writer("test.mp4",format="FFMPEG",mode="I",codec="gif")

Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'gif', auto-selecting format 'bgr8'
[mp4 @ 000002330fbede40] Could not find tag for codec gif in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

from imageio import get_writer 
writer=get_writer("test.mp4",format="FFMPEG",mode="I",codec="ffv1")

[mp4 @ 000001cdc94fde40] Could not find tag for codec ffv1 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Comment: Can't help you with `imageio` but if my [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) may work for you. If you have any questions/issues, feel free to post on Github.